# Multiple accounts created with same Facebook login in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am seeing duplicate accounts being created using the same Facebook login on Azure AD B2C.  My understanding has always been that using the combined sign-up/sign-in policy, if a user taps a social provider, Azure AD B2C will sign them back in using the same Azure AD B2C account if they created it using Facebook rather than creating a new one.

In this case however, I have three examples where 2 Azure AD B2C accounts exist with the same email address, created by the user using Facebook as the authentication mechanism. They share the same name and profile photo but have different Azure AD AD object id's.

There is a known outstanding Facebook issue around expired tokens which was acknowledged by Microsoft and is logged on UserVoice here after a paid developer support issue was logged on the Azure portal: [Fix the faulty Facebook integration and more transparency please!](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32582935-fix-the-faulty-facebook-integration-and-more-trans)

I have logged this here under the request from Azure Support on Twitter:

https://twitter.com/AzureSupport/status/949258937915895809

Please assist - we are very concerned about these issues with regards B2C's integration with a very popular social provider!

Comment: Are you using standard policies or custom policies?

Comment: Standard policies - Happy to get in contact over Skype and allow access to my domain if it helps resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Millions of end users use facebook to register and login to apps secured by Azure AD B2C.

If you are sure that the same facebook user(same user id) registered into the b2c app, then it may be possible that you used different facebook Application IDs.   In which case you would have different facebook ids presented to b2c, resulting in 2 different Azure AD B2C user accounts.

Alternatively, it is possible that a single facebook user with email joe@email.com registerd into b2c using their facebook login and later selected "local account" and created a local user (non facebook) using the same email joe@email.com.  These would appear as 2 different users.

Comment: We are aware of that situation already.  We have a number of users who have done just that which is caused by completely forgetting which provider they used when they sign in again.  They then end up creating a new "local" account and because B2C still doesn't support tying multiple accounts with the same email address together, we have to handle that ourselves.  You may be correct with the different facebook app ids so I'l double check on that.  However - can you give me any idea when we are likely to see a fix for the facebook token expiry issue which is apparently a known issue?

Comment: I suspect the multiple accounts issue is likely to be the application ID @Jose mentioned.  However, the facebook token expiry issue is still pending.